# Unknown props in React Shuffle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shuffle

I'm getting this warning when I use [React Shuffle](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle) component

***bundle.js:8335 Warning: Unknown props `duration`, `fade`, `initial` on  tag. Remove these props from the element.***

Render method of shuffle is as follows :

```
render() {
    let { initial, fade, duration, ...props } = this.props;
    var showContainer = initial ? 0 : 1;
    if (this.state.ready) {
      showContainer = 0;
    }
    return (
      <div ref="container" style={{position: 'relative'}} {...props}>
        <div style={{opacity: showContainer}}>
          {this._childrenWithRefs()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

And my package.json file is as follows :

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.4.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.6",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-shuffle": "^2.0.0",
    "react-telephone-input": "^3.5.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
  }
}
```

On the site [here](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle/pull/25/commits/0e2fe2b33a1fc87fe41af271202acab3174036a6) they say that the problem is solved. But I have the same configuration and I made those changes, but the problem still exists..

Any advice?